# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp in computing the logistic function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm getting this error when I try to compute the logistic function for a data mining method I'm implementing:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

My code:

```
def logistic_function(x):
#     x = np.float64(x)
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))
```

If I understood correctly from some related questions that the problem is that np.exp() is returning a huge value. I saw suggestions to let numpy ignore the warnings, but the problem is that when I get this error, then the results of my method are horrible. However when I don't get it, then they are as expected. So making numpy ignoring the warning is not a solution for me at all. I don't know what is wrong or how to deal with.

I don't even know if this is a result of a bug because sometimes I get this error and sometimes not! I went through my code many times and everything looks correct!

Comment: You are just trying to calculate numbers that are too big to fit in 8 bytes (float 64). Solution: Filter your data for values small enough that make sense.

Answer (score 14):

You should compute the logistic function using either [`scipy.special.expit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html), which **in recent enough SciPy** is more stable than your solution (although earlier versions got it wrong), or by reducing it to `tanh`:

```
def logistic_function(x):
    return .5 * (1 + np.tanh(.5 * x))
```

This version of the function is stable, fast, and fairly accurate.

Comment: `x` is likely very negative, try this to reproduce the warning: `np.exp(1e3)`